# using ObjectOutput/InputStream to read/write from custom location

Tags: java, android

i have read the developer info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html), but i'm not sure I'm doing this right. I want my file on the External Storage (SD Card).

`ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyAppName/FileName.srl")));

out.writeObject( MyObject );

out.close();`

This will compile, but i need to know 1 thing: Can another app with the exact same class of MyObject read and write from this serialized file? or will it somehow fail for apps with different UserIDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the identical version of the class is used in both apps, the two apps will be able to read/write each other's serialized streams.

If you haven't already done so, you should declare a `static final long serialVersionUID` in your serializable class, in order to detect any possible version incompatibilities in the future.